# Undefined function or variable

Tags: matlab

I have a simple function as below:

```
function  dz = statespace(t,z)
dz = A*z + B*k*z
end
```

My main script is :

```
clear all;close all;format short;clc;
% step 1 -- input system parameters 
% structure data
M1 = 1; M2= 1; M3= 1;                         %Lumped Mass(Tons)
M= diag([M1,M2,M3]);
k(1)= 980; k(2)= 980; k(3)= 980;              %Stiffness Coefficient(KN/M)
K = zeros(3,3);
for i=1:2
K(i,i)=k(i)+k(i+1);
end
K(3,3)=k(3);
for i=1:2
K(i,i+1)=-k(i+1);
end
for i=2:3
K(i,i-1)=-k(i);
end                                           %Stiffness Matrix(KN/M)
c(1)= 1.407; c(2)= 1.407; c(3)= 1.407;        %Damping Coefficient(KN.sec/M)
C = zeros(3,3);
for i=1:2
C(i,i)=c(i)+c(i+1);
end
C(3,3)=c(3);
for i=1:2
C(i,i+1)=-c(i+1);
end
for i=2:3
C(i,i-1)=-c(i);
end                                           %Damping Matrix(KN.sec/M)
 A = [zeros(3) eye(3);-inv(M)*K -inv(M)*C]
 H = [1;0;0]
 B = [0;0;0;inv(M)*H]
 k = [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 t = 0:0.004:10; 
 [t,z] = ode45(statespace,t);
```

When I run my main script it comes with following error:

`Undefined function or variable 'A'.`

`Error in statespace (line 2)
    dz = A*z + B*k*z`

As you can see I defined `A` in main script. Why this problem happening?

Comment: Your function only knows what you feed it as inputs (in this case, `t` and `z`). In other words, `A`, `B` and `k` are not in the scope of your `statespace` function.

Comment: You mean I should define them again in function script?

Comment: No; you should instead modify the definition of your function so that it accept three more inputs corresponding to `A`, `B`, and `k`.

Comment: Can you please explain it a little more?
I searched every where in net but I couldn't find anything useful.Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There multiple things wrong with your code. First, you need to supply the values of A and B to your function but as you are invoking it (incorrectly without the @ and additional parameter y0 as I commented below) in the toolbox ode45, you have to keep just two parameters so you cannot supply A and B as additional parameters. If you define A and B within your function or share them via global variables you will get further. However, as noted below the definitions don't seem to be correct as A * z and B * k * z don't have the same dimensions. z is a scalar so B * k needs to be same size and shape as A which currently it is not.

Edit from: 
As Jubobs suggested change your function's parameters to include A, B and k. Also you don't need t as it is never used in the function. So:

```
function  dz = statespace(A, B, k, z)
   dz = A*z + B*k*z
end
```

Comment: I have tried it before but if you run the codes, you'll see it is returning the same error ...

Comment: Okay but now the error is somewhat different and is coming from your call to ode45. You need to pass a handle to the function statespace using @statespace but in this case you need to supply an additional parameter y0 as defined in the ode45 documentation. So you would have [t,z] = ode45(@statespace,t, y0); but you need to define y0.

Comment: y0=0, however it seems that the problem is in the second line of my function.

Comment: Yes there is still a problem. Looks like ode45 expects a function with only two parameters (t and y) - so you will either need to define A and B inside your function or make them available some other way either using global variables or using one of the scoping mechanisms available in Matlab.

Comment: If you transfer most of your script inside the function it gets further but then complains that A * z and B * k * z don't have the same dimensions. z is a scalar so B * k needs to be same size and shape as A which currently it is not. Looks like your definition of B is not quite right perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, `A`, `B` and `k` are not defined in the function workspace, so you either need to define them again (ugly, not recommended), declare them as global variables (slightly better, but still not good practice), or pass them as arguments to your function (the better solution). However, because you then want to use the function with `ode45`, you need to be a bit careful with how you do it:

```
function  dz = statespace(t,z,A,B,k)
   dz = A*z + B*k*z
end
```

and then the call to `ode45` would like this:

```
[t,z] = ode45(@(t,z)statespace(t,z,A,B,k),[0 Tf],z0); % where Tf is your final time and z0 your initial conditions
```

See [Error using ode45 and deval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327129/error-using-ode45-and-deval/) for a similar problem.